# Story where an immortal man has his memory wiped every 100 years

Tags: story-identification

Author of [this article](http://www.ribbonfarm.com/2016/04/21/a-framework-of-experimental-habit-formation/) describes a short sci-fi story:

> The story centered on a man living in a futuristic, hyper-prosperous civilization. All of society’s problems had been solved, and death was a distant memory. It had been discovered that humans are not meant to live more than about 125 years. It wasn’t a limitation of physics, biology, neurology, or technology — it was a fundamental limit of conscious self-awareness. Each passing year brought more reasons to not do things than to do them, gradually narrowing into a nihilistic tunnel vision that led inevitably to insanity. The main character developed a strategy to cope: every 100 years he dedicated to a personal passion, at the end of which he would have his mind wiped, only to start again on something else. The story recounts the final moments of a century dedicated to the study of insects. Gazing on cases upon cases of meticulously collected and catalogued bugs from every corner of the world, the man reminisces about his vast entomological experience. As the clock winds down and the mind-wipe begins to take effect, he looks forward to his reincarnation with a childlike anticipation that he hasn’t felt in years.

He himself [does not remember](http://www.ribbonfarm.com/2016/04/21/a-framework-of-experimental-habit-formation/#comment-253546) the title.

Does anyone recognize it?

Comment: One of the subplots of Greg Egan's [Permutation City](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_City) involves a man who gives himself a series of all-consuming passions for a while before moving on to the next one, but the rest of the details don't match.

Comment: It's not the same story, but Henry Kuttner's ["A Cross of Centuries"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57500) is also about an immortal man who has his memory cleared every 100 years.

Comment: There is a related plot element in *Gods of the Greataway* -- the Everlings, immortal children who live on The People Planet, have regular cycles of creation and destruction. But no memory wiping, not much else matches.

Comment: @user14111 I went to the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/crossofcenturies00mich/page/380/mode/2up) to read this. It does feature a man who wipes his memory every 100 years ... but almost nothing else matches. No entomology for sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This does sound like a misremembering of Egan's "Permutation City"

**Gazing on cases upon cases of meticulously collected and catalogued bugs from every corner of the world, the man reminisces about his vast entomological experience. As the clock winds down and the mind-wipe begins to take effect, he looks forward to his reincarnation with a childlike anticipation that he hasn’t felt in years.**

> The workshop abutted a warehouse full of table legs—one hundred and
> sixty-two thousand, three hundred and twenty-nine, so far.  Peer
> could imagine nothing more satisfying than reaching the two hundred
> thousand mark—although he knew it was likely that he'd change his mind
> and abandon the workshop before that happened; new vocations were
> imposed by his exoself at random intervals, but statistically, the
> next one was overdue.  Immediately before taking up woodwork, he'd
> passionately devoured all the higher mathematics texts in the central
> library, run all the tutorial software, and then personally
> contributed several important new results to group theory—untroubled
> by the fact that none of the Elysian mathematicians would ever be
> aware of his work.  Before that, he'd written over three hundred comic
> operas, with librettos in Italian, French and English—and staged most
> of them, with puppet performers and audience.  Before that, he'd
> patiently studied the structure and biochemistry of the human brain
> for sixty-seven years; towards the end he had fully grasped, to his
> own satisfaction, the nature of the process of consciousness.  Every
> one of these pursuits had been utterly engrossing, and satisfying, at
> the time.  He'd even been interested in the Elysians, once.
> No longer.  He preferred to think about table legs.

> Peer felt the change begin, and switched off the lathe. He looked
> around the workshop helplessly, his eyes alighting on object after
> object which he couldn't imagine living without: the belt sander, the
> rack full of cutting tools for the lathe, cans of oil, tins of
> varnish.

> Then the empty ground grew a vast room around him, stretching in all
> directions for hundreds of meters, full of row after row of yellow
> wooden specimen drawers.
>
> The drawers, he knew, were full of beetles. Hundreds of thousands of
> beetles. He was free, now, to do nothing with his time but study them,
> sketch them, annotate them, classify them: specimen by specimen,
> species by species, decade after decade. The prospect was so blissful
> that he almost keeled over with joy.

Comment: Part of *Permutation City* was adapted from the short story "Dust" which appeared in Asimov's in 1992, so I went looking at that. It doesn't match -- no 100 year reset -- so the original blog author didn't read it there.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty sure that’s ***[A.D.: After Death](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25534845-a-d-after-death-book-one)*** (2016) by Scott Snyder.

> WHAT IF WE FOUND A CURE FOR DEATH? Two of comics’ most acclaimed creators, SCOTT SNYDER (WYTCHES, Batman, American Vampire) and JEFF LEMIRE (DESCENDER, Moon Knight, Sweet Tooth) unite to create a three-part epic like no other, set in a future where a genetic cure for death has been found. Years after the discovery, one man starts to question everything, leading him on a mind-bending journey that will bring him face-to-face with his past and his own mortality. A unique combination of comics, prose, and illustration, A.D.: AFTER DEATH will be serialized monthly as three oversized prestige format books written by SNYDER and fully painted by LEMIRE.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that's the correct story, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question?

Comment: After Death was first published in late 2016 so is unlikely to be the correct answer to a question from April 2016, even if it otherwise matches.